# ¿Cómo poner una variable dentro de otra variable en PHP?

Tags: php, variables

Quiero meter una variable en un `$_POST[$variable]` pero no encuentro cómo hacerlo. `$dato` viene de un formulario con varias opciones, y dependiendo de lo que el cliente ha seleccionado, `$dato2` debe tomar ese valor.

¿Ayuda? Gracias.

Este es el código:

```
$dato2 = " ";

$dato = $_POST[$dato2];


switch ($dato){

    case "nombre":
    $dato2 = "nombre";
    break;

    case "direccion";
    $dato2 = "direccion";
    break;

    case "email";
    $dato2 = "email";
    break;

    case "telefono1";
    $dato2 = "telefono1";
    break;

    case "telefono2";
    $dato2 = "telefono2";
    break;

    case "modelo";
    $dato2 = "modelo";
    break;
}
```

Comment: Indicanos las posibilidades que tiene o tendrá la variable `$_POST`

Answer (score 2):

He intentado lo que me habéis dicho pero no me ha funcionado. Con la idea del `isset` de Jorge Bravo he hecho esto y ya he conseguido hacer lo que quería.

Tengo un `input='text'` en la página anterior, y este `input` puede tener varios valores según el cliente elige, y yo recibo el valor por `post` y tengo que darle otro en esta otra página.

Lo he conseguido así:

```
 $dato1 = $_POST['nombre'];
 $dato2 = $_POST['direccion'];
 $dato3 = $_POST['email'];
 $dato4 = $_POST['telefono1'];
 $dato5 = $_POST['telefono2'];
 $dato6 = $_POST['modelo'];

 if(isset($dato1)){
  $dato = $dato1;
 }

 if(isset($dato2)){
  $dato = $dato2;
 }

 if(isset($dato3)){
  $dato = $dato3;
 }

 if(isset($dato4)){
  $dato = $dato4;
 }

 if(isset($dato5)){
  $dato = $dato5;
 }

 if(isset($dato6)){
  $dato = $dato6;
 }


 switch ($dato){

    case "nombre":
     $dato = $_POST["nombre"];
    break;

    case "direccion":
     $dato = $_POST["direccion"];
    break;

    case "email":
     $dato = $_POST["email"];
    break;

    case "telefono1":
     $dato = $_POST["telefono1"];
    break;

    case "telefono2":
     $dato = $_POST["telefono2"];
    break;

    case "modelo":
     $dato = $_POST["modelo"];
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

puedes probar a hacer esto

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['btnEnviar'])){
    $Nombre=$_POST['Nombre'];
    $Apellido=$_POST['Apellido']...

switch ($dato){

    case "nombre":
    nombre = $Nombre;
    break;
}

}
```